# AJAX based page needs repetitive javascript actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on an application that uses JQuery layouts and loads only website parts (like Gmail). Every time I load a "panel" using JQuery I have to substitute some links to make it work with panels (i.e., to load this link content in a panel, not in the full page). Is something like this:

```
function changeMainPane(href) {
    $("#screen").load(href);
    $("#screen a.ajax-page").click(function () {return
        changeMainPane($(this).attr("href"))
    });
}
```

This is a very simplified *changeMainPane* function, mine has tens of *$("#screen ...").click()* calls to integrate the new piece of HTML into the page.

The question is: there is any better way to do this? Something like:

```
$("#screen").ready(function() {
    // All my html setups
}
```

Or something like "always a user clicks on a link, check if has ajax-page class and the call this function" without having to initialize each link independently.

Comment: Today also similar question was asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771954/dynamically-create-js-function/6771976#6771976

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method. The delegate method can be registered for the common parent element of all the links on which you wants to reload the main panel. It can be the `document` object or a lower level element like `"body"` or another div like `"div.mylinks"`.

```
$(document).delegate("a.ajax-page", "click", function(){
    changeMainPane($(this).attr("href"))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe jQuery `live()` is what you're looking for. You use it like this:

```
$("#screen a.ajax-page").live('click', function () { whatever; });
```

Then you don't need to reinitizalize after ajax activity.